# Jackson Scala Module, nested Lists and Maps

Tags: json, scala, nested, jackson

I wish to convert lists of json objects, which in themselves may contain Json objects, or Lists of Json objects and would like the results to be Scala Maps or Lists as appropriate, however, I can only get the top level object to convert to a Map or a List. 
Is there a simple way to do this?

For example in REPL

```
objectMapper.readValue("{\"test\":\"113123\",\"myList\":[{\"test2\":\"321323\"},{\"test3\":\"11122\"}]}", classOf[Map[String,Any]])
```

Will return

```
res: Map[String,Any] = Map(test -> 113123, myList -> [{test2=321323}, {test3=11122}])
```

Where I would like

```
res: Map[String,Any] = Map(test -> 113123, myList -> List(Map(test2 -> 321323), Map(test3 -> 111222)))
```

Comment: Do you really need to use Jackson? Using lift-json with case classes is much simpler.

Comment: If mapping works, there is nothing complicated in using Jackson data-binding: how would lift-json be simpler than one liner shown above?

Comment: I have used lift and Jackson, and found lift was having memory issues when processing 15,000+ json objects, where as Jackson was handling this fine

Comment: I constructed the object mapper to use with mapModule and seqModule

Comment: I have yet to try jerkson, is there a jar available?(I'm new to the jvm and haven't worked out the building jars from github yet..)

Comment: Jerkson depends on Jackson 1.9.x.  You can get it from http://repo.codahale.com/com/codahale/jerkson_2.9.0-1/0.4.2/jerkson_2.9.0-1-0.4.2.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so using a later version of the scala jackson module I created this class

```
private class NestedTypeObjectDeserializer extends JacksonUntypedObjectDeserializer {

  override def mapArray(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): AnyRef =
    super.mapArray(jp, ctxt).asInstanceOf[ArrayList[AnyRef]].asScala.toList

  override def mapObject(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): AnyRef =
    super.mapObject(jp, ctxt).asInstanceOf[LinkedHashMap[String, AnyRef]].asScala.toMap
}


private object NestedTypeObjectDeserializerResolver extends Deserializers.Base {

  lazy val OBJECT = classOf[AnyRef]

  override def findBeanDeserializer(javaType: JavaType,
                                    config: DeserializationConfig,
                                    beanDesc: BeanDescription) =
    if (!OBJECT.equals(javaType.getRawClass)) null
    else new NestedTypeObjectDeserializer
}

trait NestedTypeObjectDeserializerModule extends JacksonModule {
  this += (_ addDeserializers NestedTypeObjectDeserializerResolver)
}
```

which you can apply to the object mapper

```
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val module = new OptionModule with MapModule with SeqModule with IteratorModule with NestedTypeObjectDeserializerModule {}
objectMapper.registerModule(module)
```

Comment: I ran into this same issue but found that if I just didn't register the UntypedObjectDeserializer it worked as I would have originally expected.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work as expected, please file an issue against Jackson Scala Module at [https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues]. It is possible that there are issues with handling of contents in "untyped" mode (i.e. non-bean, using Lists, Maps etc) which scala module needs to add special handling for. The underlying challenge is that Scala collections in general do not map cleanly with JDK collections.

Comment: Good, let's hope it gets addresses quickly!

Comment: This has been fixed, created new answer to show code you need to use

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Jackson Scala Module, but the behavior is the same in Jerkson, so I'll hazard a guess as to what's going on.  When the REPL is printing:

```
myList -> [{test2=321323}, {test3=11122}])
```

it's telling you that there's a tuple containing "myList" and an java.util.ArrayList.  The ArrayList contains two java.util.LinkedHashMaps.  (I explain this because it wasn't obvious to me at first and I had to spend some quality time with the REPL using getClass and asInstanceOf  to dive into that structure.)

I'm fairly certain there's not a way to get Jackson Scala Module or Jerkson to return deserialized JSON with native Scala collections.  You can import [scala.collect.JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions%24.html) to make the those values appear a little more Scala-like.  Even if you do that, you'll still have to cast things around.  For example:

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
import collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util._
res("myList").asInstanceOf[ArrayList[LinkedHashMap[String,String]]](0)("test2")
  >> String = 321323
```

If you don't want to have to fiddle with all of the casting, I think what you need to do is define a class to deserialize to.  So for example, using Jerkson:

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
import collection.immutable.{Map,List}

case class MyClass(test: Integer, myList: List[Map[String,String]])

object M {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val t =parse[MyClass]("""{"test":"113123","myList":[{"test2":"321323"},{"test3":"11122"}]}""")
    println(t.myList(0)("test2"))
  }
}
```

(The reason I wrote that as a full program is that Jerkson doesn't handle deserializing case classes in the REPL.)

I know you can deserialize to an object with Jackson, but last time I looked it took a few more steps.

Is this on the right track to answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I followed Leif's advice and wrote this code to solve the problem

```
private def mapToMap(map:java.util.Map[String,Any]) : Map[String,Any] = {
  val mb = new MapBuilder[String, Any, HashMap[String, String]](new HashMap[String, String])
  val iterator = map.keySet().iterator
  while (iterator.hasNext) {
    val key = iterator.next
    mb += (key -> checkValue(map.get(key)))
  }

  mb.result
}

private def arrayToList(array:java.util.ArrayList[Any]) : List[Any] = {
  val lb = new ListBuffer[Any]()
  val iterator = array.iterator
  while(iterator.hasNext) lb += checkValue(iterator.next)
  lb.result
}

private def checkValue(value:Any) : Any = value match {
  case l: java.util.ArrayList[Any] => arrayToList(l)
  case m: java.util.Map[String,Any] => mapToMap(m)
  case _ => value
}
```